# How to validate Angular2 form controls that depend on eachother?

Tags: angular, validation, typescript

I am trying to create a time picker component that binds to a reactive form control. I want the form control to be invalid if the end time is before the start time. I am aware of the built in validators that Angular comes with, but I want to be able to validate against another form control. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

Answer (score 3):

This is the approach I take:

- Define the validator on the `FormGroup` containing the two controls.
- In the validator, use the `FormGroup` object that is passed in to retrieve the values of the two `FormControl` objects and perform the validation.

Comment: Where exactly and how should I define the validator? Just adding a validator as second parameter (https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#constructor()) after the form controls doesn't have any effect for me.