# conditional validation of Angular reactive forms

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I am new to angular and working on reactive form.

I have a html table in which by looping through I have generated controls
[image: Table]

I want to add validation based on following cases

1. When this page loads than by default Save button should be disabled( which I have achieved by used  `[disabled]="!myform.valid"`
2. Save button should enable only when user enter value in any of text boxes or select check box in that particular row.
   **Checkbox select and add value in text box should not allow to user.**
   Either checkbox should be selected or user can enter value in any of text-boxes.

I tried this to achieve

```
IsFormValid(){return (!!this.myfm.get('myform').value);}// but this returning always true.
```

Here it my code

```
    myfm:FormGroup;
  ngOnInit() {
  debugger;
  this.myfm = this.fb.group({
  myform: this.fb.array([this.addformFileds()])
  }); 
}

 addformFileds(): FormGroup {
  return this.fb.group({
  NoTask: ['', Validators.required],// only check box is required either checkbox should click 
 or enter value in any text-boxes
                                    
  task1: ['', null],    
  task2: ['', null],
  task3: ['', null],
  task4: ['', null],
  task5: ['', null],
  task6: ['', null],
  task7: ['', null],
  task8: ['', null],
  task9: ['', null],
  task10: ['', null],
  task11: ['', null],
  task12: ['', null] 
});
}

 //adding more rows on click of Add More Rows button
addEntried():void{
this.idAddNewRow=true; //indicator that new rows is being created 
(<FormGroup>this.myfm.get('myform')).push(this.addEntried());
}
```

I know if is bit tricky but still didn't get solution for this. Any help of this will very helpful for me.

My  component.html code

```
 <form #frmImp='NgForm' [formGroup]="myfm"]>
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header" style="align-items: center"> 
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">       
   <!--<table class="table-bordered table-responsive" style="overflow-x: true;"> to disable the scroll bar if screen resolution is less than 1920x1080-->
            <table class="table-bordered " >
      <thead>
          <tr style="border-bottom-style: solid"><td id="" class=""  colspan="15" style="text-align: center"><b>Imp Task Details</b></td>
          </tr> 
          <tr>
            <th style="text-align: center;"> </th>
            <th style="text-align: center;"> </th>
            <th style="text-align: center;">No Task</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;">Task 1</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;">Task 2</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;">Task 3</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;">Task 4</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;">Task 5</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;">Task 6</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;">Task 7</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;">Task 8</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;">Task 9</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;">Task 10</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;">Task 11</th>
            <th style="text-align: center;">Task 12</th> 
       
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody formArrayName="myform" **ngFor="let frm of myfm.get('myform')['controls']; let i=index">
          <tr [[formGroupName]="i"]>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><input [id]="'txt'+i" type="checkbox" formControlName="NoTask" style="margin-left: 30px;"/></td> 
            <td  ><input [id]="'txt'+i" type="tex" class="textboxFormat" formControlName="task1"   placeholder="0"></td>
            <td ><input [id]="'txt'+i" type="tex" class="textboxFormat"   formControlName="task2" ></td>
            <td ><input [id]="'txt'+i" type="tex" class="textboxFormat"   formControlName="task3" ></td>
            <td ><input [id]="'txt'+i" type="tex" class="textboxFormat"   formControlName="task4" ></td>
            <td ><input [id]="'txt'+i" type="tex" class="textboxFormat"   formControlName="task5" ></td>
            <td ><input [id]="'txt'+i" type="tex" class="textboxFormat"   formControlName="task6" ></td>
            <td ><input [id]="'txt'+i" type="tex" class="textboxFormat"   formControlName="task7" ></td>
            <td ><input [id]="'txt'+i" type="tex" class="textboxFormat"   formControlName="task8" ></td>
            <td ><input [id]="'txt'+i" type="tex" class="textboxFormat"   formControlName="task9" ></td>
            <td ><input [id]="'txt'+i" type="tex" class="textboxFormat"  formControlName="task10" ></td>
            <td ><input [id]="'txt'+i" type="tex" class="textboxFormat"  formControlName="task11" ></td>
            <td ><input [id]="'txt'+i" type="tex" class="textboxFormat"   formControlName="task12" ></td>  
          </tr>
           
        </tbody>
    </table> 
  </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" *ngIf="isAvailable" (click)="addformFileds()">Add More Rows </button> 
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" (click)=SaveImpDetails(frmImp)>Save </button> 
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>


**component.ts** file code
SaveImpDetails(){
   this.baseSrvc.post(ApiResource.SaveImpDetails, 
    JSON.stringify(body)).subscribe((result=>{
if(result){
   this.alertService.showMessage("Success!", "Details has been 
    recorded 
    successfuly.")
 }if(result.isError){
 this.alert.showMessage("Error!! while saving details");
}
  }));
   }
```

Comment: See if this helps -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52866016/conditional-required-validation-in-angular-reactive-form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**:

After understanding the whole question, we could resolve it by adding a new validator to each form item.

Here is the reproduction example(You can see the same on the Stackblitz):

```js
  myfm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() { this._generateForm(); }

  private _generateForm() {
    this.myfm = this.fb.group({
      myform: this.fb.array([this.addformFileds()]),
    });
  }

  addformFileds(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group(
      {
        NoTask: '',
        task1: '',
        task2: '',
        task3: '',
        task4: '',
        task5: '',
        task6: '',
        task7: '',
        task8: '',
        task9: '',
        task10: '',
        task11: '',
        task12: '',
      },
      { validator: [validateRow()] }
    );
  }
```

and the helper function and validator

```js
function validateRow(): ValidatorFn {
  const pairs: string[][] = [
    ['task1', 'task2'],
    ['task3', 'task4'],
    ['task5', 'task6'],
    ['task7', 'task8'],
    ['task9', 'task10'],
    ['task11', 'task12'],
  ];
  return (group: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null => {
    if (group.get('NoTask').value) {
      return null;
    }

    // check the pair validities
    const invalidPair = pairs.find((pair) => {
      const firstTask = group.get(pair[0]).value;
      const secondTask = group.get(pair[1]).value;

      if ((firstTask && !secondTask) || (!firstTask && secondTask)) {
        return true;
      }

      return false;
    });

    // return pair validity error object
    if (invalidPair) {
      return { invalidPair };
    }

    if (!singleWhere(group, (item) => item.value)) {
      return {invalidRow: true};
    }

    return null;
  };
}

/**
 * find and return the first control for which
 * the `callback` function returns `true`
 *
 * loop over the `group` controls
 * and return the `control`
 * if the `callback` function returns `true` for the `control`
 *
 * @param group - is the form
 * @param callback - is the callback function
 *
 * @return `AbstractControl`
 */
 function singleWhere(
  group: AbstractControl,
  callback: (control: AbstractControl, index: number) => boolean
): AbstractControl {
  if (!group) {
    return null;
  }
  if (group instanceof FormControl) {
    return callback(group, 0) ? group : null;
  }

  const keys = Object.keys((group as FormGroup).controls);

  for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    const control = group?.get(keys[i]);

    if (singleWhere(control, callback)) {
      return group;
    }
  }

  return null;
}
```

And finally, in the template, add disable attribute by this condition

```
[disabled]="myfm.invalid || myfm.untouched"
```

Here is the reproduction example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-4-starter-vvimke?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Hi @ashot I tried this but not working, after using this when I select any control it blur our the button and when I leave cursor from control it should blue back which is not. I have added the html code in the question, please see.

Comment: @VirenderThakur can you please add the buttons as well?

Comment: Just updated. Please see.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Check the link(I have updated the answer)

Comment: Ok thanks!!,, as I can see when page load first time save button disabled which should be. but when I start typing in any of textboxes and remove the text and leaving it button is not blur back. If I have typed something and erase it than it should disabled the save button because user didn't enter in it.

Comment: ah, I see now, what you mean, we can resolve it by listening `valueChanges`. I will share an example in about hour.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240466/discussion-between-virender-thakur-and-ashot-aleqsanyan).

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-4-starter-4kmswc?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: can you please check the link

Comment: it is working when I am typing in the textbox but when I just want to select checkbox it should also unblur the button

Comment: yeah, the problem is that, the checkbox should have her own `formControl`, you need to add `formControlName` on it

Comment: Yes it does have sorry I forget to add in the post. Please see the updated post.

Comment: ok, no problem, check again, the same link

Comment: just make sure, you can see the new added `formControlName` in the HTML

Comment: Thnx @ashot for help. Will it work with dynamic controls as well. If I have n number of rows with same control in each row??

Comment: @VirenderThakur no problem, It should. It is checking all of the form controls

Comment: I want to disable/enable the textbox if users checked/uncheck the checkbox. Is that possible in your example.

Comment: Actually disable save button is working but if I type some data in any textboxes and than I also can select the checkbox same time which I don't want to do. Either all or any textbox value should submit or only check box value should allow.

Comment: It is another logic that can be combined with the current one

Comment: can you give me insight on this how to achieve this as well.

Comment: sure, just share `SaveImpDetails` function as well

Comment: just updated the question please check.

Comment: ok, got you checking now

Comment: lets continue here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240466/discussion-between-virender-thakur-and-ashot-aleqsanyan

Comment: Hi @Ashot Aleqsanyan, I know its been a while but I have one scenario in the same example, I want to validate each pair or textvalues, if there is any value in task1 textbox than there should also value in task2 and so on.  so there are 12 textboxex in this way 6 pairs of textboxes. If user enter values lets say in task3 textbox than task4 text should also have value otherwise disable the save button.

Comment: Hi @VirenderThakur I have updated the answer, and the stackblitz example, let me know if it works for you

Comment: Thank you!! @Ashot Aleqsanyan. Glad you responded.

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a FormArray for the tasks? As you has a formArray and inside a formArray you should use two functions:

```
  //you can defined your formArray like
  formArray=this.fb.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7].map(_=>this.addformFields()))

  getGroup(i)
  {
    return this.formArray.at(i) as FormGroup
  }

  tasks(i)
  {
    return this.getGroup(i).get('tasks') as FormArray
  }
```

Your function addformFields becomes like

```
  addformFields(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      noTask:false,
      tasks:this.fb.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11].map(_=>this.fb.control(0)))
    },{validator:this.someValue()})
  }
```

And the validator is like

```
  someValue(){
    return (control:AbstractControl)=>{
      const group=control as FormGroup;
      let valid=control.get('noTask').value;
      (control.get('tasks') as FormArray).controls.forEach(x=>{
        valid=valid || +x.value!=0
      })
      return valid?null:{error:"You shoul indicate one task or that there' not task"}
    }
  }
```

The .html to control the FormArray

```
<table class="form-group">
  <tr>
    <th>Section</th>
    <th *ngFor="let i of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]">Task {{ i }}</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr
      *ngFor="let group of formArray.controls; let i = index"
      [formGroup]="getGroup(i)"
    >
      <td><input type="checkbox" formControlName="noTask" /></td>
      <ng-container formArrayName="tasks">
        <td *ngFor="let control of tasks(i).controls; let j = index">
          <input
            [attr.disabled]="getGroup(i).get('noTask').value ? true : null"
            [formControlName]="j"
          />
        </td>
      </ng-container>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

See that if, e.g. you defined a .css like

```
tr.ng-invalid.ng-touched input{
  border:1px solid red;
}
tr.ng-invalid.ng-touched input:focus{
  border-color:   red;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  border-width: 2px;
  outline: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 .15rem rgba(255,0,0,.25);
}
```

A [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tvldwu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Thanx @Eliseo for this. Quick question these controls are dynamically generated and can be any number what need to add instead of this [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11].map . 1 to 11

Comment: you always can generate an array "on-fly" with a variable "cant" and string.repeat. e.g. `'.'.repeat(cant).split('')` create an array of "." with length "cant". You can also use in .ts iterate=new Array(this.cant);this.iterate.fill('.')`